# notification not firing after switching viewContrller

Tags: ios, uiview, uilocalnotification

I am back with one very strange issue in my current project and it goes like this: 
1. UIViewcontroller which holds scrollView. 
2.ScrollView indeed loads 3 views with xib from nib as follows :

```
   `CGRect frame = self.mainScrollView.bounds;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = -66;

    id publicView =[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[viewNameArray objectAtIndex:page] owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [publicView setDelegate:self];
    [publicView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [publicView setFrame:frame];
    [self.mainScrollView addSubview:publicView];`
```

1. And above views contains some NSnotications. 
   But here problem is notifications calls only for the first time when views are loaded. If we navigate to different view controller and come back to the same view controller which has the scroll view notifications does not call. Can any one suggest whats wrong with the architecture I made.

Comment: I think you need to show your which contain notification in order to help figuring out the problem.

Comment: I love these questions. Shows code which is great. Is the code in anyway related to the question? No. You probably answered your own question when you said "notifications calls only for the first time when views are loaded". Also consider where/ if you are removing observer if you are adding the observer back when you are returning to the view.

Answer (score 1):

Your notifications are likely in your init or viewDidLoad methods of your view controller. Instead place them in your viewWillAppear method to ensure that they are called every time the view controller is displayed. Add this code to your view controller that calls the notifications.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // post your notifications here
}
```